# Import data with pandas read_csv: header with two rows error

Tags: python, pandas, import

I am trying to import data from a text file using pandas. The data looks like this:

```
  Step            Time    Pressure z=0  MoleFrac 1 z=0  MoleFrac 2 z=0   Mole flow z=0
 [Int]       [seconds]         [bar.a]             [-]             [-]       [gmole/s]
     1       0.0000000  7.75425808E-01  1.30000000E-01  8.70000000E-01  6.00000000E-02
     2       0.0556727  7.67785502E-01  1.30000000E-01  8.70000000E-01  6.00000000E-02
     3       0.5673533  7.18327020E-01  1.30000000E-01  8.70000000E-01  6.00000000E-02
```

I tried to do it like this:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('filename.txt', delimiter="\s+", header=[0,1])
```

It works if I only use one row for the header but as soon as I add the 2nd one, I get an error message:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The problem seems to be with the delimiter. Replacing the spaces between the columns with a `,` and setting the delimiter to the same character worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r"filename.txt",  delimiter="\s{2,}", header=[0,1], engine='python')
```

When `engine` is set to `python` then there is possible to use regular expression as delimiter.

Result:

```
   Step      Time Pressure z=0 MoleFrac 1 z=0 MoleFrac 2 z=0 Mole flow z=0
  [Int] [seconds]      [bar.a]            [-]            [-]     [gmole/s]
0     1  0.000000     0.775426           0.13           0.87          0.06
1     2  0.055673     0.767786           0.13           0.87          0.06
2     3  0.567353     0.718327           0.13           0.87          0.06
```

Because there are single spaces in column names, I've found that delimiter should be at least 2 spaces `"  "` which is expressed as `\s{2,}`.

Check `df.columns`:

```
MultiIndex([(          'Step',     '[Int]'),
            (          'Time', '[seconds]'),
            (  'Pressure z=0',   '[bar.a]'),
            ('MoleFrac 1 z=0',       '[-]'),
            ('MoleFrac 2 z=0',       '[-]'),
            ( 'Mole flow z=0', '[gmole/s]')],
           )
```

so the resulting dataframe looks correct.

Comment: Nice to hear it! Consider accepting solution as an answer please.